# What language/tool should I use for HTML parsing?

Tags: html, screen-scraping, html-parsing

I have a couple of websites that I want to extract data from and based on previous experiences, this isn't as easy as it sound. Why? Simply because the HTML pages I have to parse aren't properly formatted (missing closing tag, etc.).

Considering that I have no constraints regarding the technology, language or tool that I can use, **what are your suggestions to easily parse and extract data from HTML pages**? I have tried HTML Agility Pack, BeautifulSoup, and even these tools aren't perfect (HTML Agility Pack is buggy, and BeautifulSoup parsing engine doesn't work with the pages I am passing to it).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "doesn't work" with regards to BeautifulSoup? I would have suggested it, otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pretty much any language you like **just don't try and parse HTML with regular expressions.**

So let me rephrase that and say: you can use any language you like that has a HTML parser, which is pretty much everything invented in the last 15-20 years.

If you're having issues with particular pages I suggest you look into repairing them with [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

I think hpricot (linked by Colin Pickard) is ace.  Add scrubyt to the mix and you get a great html scraping and browsing interface with the text matching power of Ruby http://scrubyt.org/

here is some example code from http://github.com/scrubber/scrubyt_examples/blob/7a219b58a67138da046aa7c1e221988a9e96c30e/twitter.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'scrubyt'

# Simple exmaple for scraping basic
# information from a public Twitter
# account.

# Scrubyt.logger = Scrubyt::Logger.new

twitter_data = Scrubyt::Extractor.define do
  fetch 'http://www.twitter.com/scobleizer'

  profile_info '//ul[@class="about vcard entry-author"]' do
    full_name "//li//span[@class='fn']"
    location "//li//span[@class='adr']"
    website "//li//a[@class='url']/@href"
    bio "//li//span[@class='bio']"
  end
end

puts twitter_data.to_xml
```

Comment: I followed the instructions on their website and I'm not able to install scribyt. Any idea?

C:\Windows\system32>gem install mechanize
Install required dependency hoe? [Yn]  Y
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    Could not find hoe (>= 1.9.0) in any repository

Comment: you might want to try installing a previous version.  Scrubyt in the past has been very specific about the versions of it's dependencies. I have it working on Mac, not Win, so can't help too much there. My compiler had to be in path to install it as an aside

Answer (score 2):

As language Java and as a open source library [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) will be a pretty solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

[hpricot](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Aye.  I upvoted Stewart Robinson (back in 2009) for that reason.  But these day you'll probably want to use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) rather than hpricot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may try PHP's [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) class. It has a couple of methods for loading HTML content. I usually make use of this class. My advises are to prepend a DOCTYPE element to the HTML in case it hasn't one and to inspect in Firebug the HTML that results after parsing. In some cases, where invalid markup is encountered, DOMDocument does a bit of rearrangement of the HTML elements. Also, if there's a meta tag specifying the charset inside the source be careful that it will be used internally by libxml when parsing the markup. Here's a little example

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$oldValue = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($oldValue);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

Any language which works with HTML on DOM level is good.

for perl it is HTML::TreeBuilder module.